# Is every finite lattice also complete?

Tags: relations, lattice-orders

I have to proof the every finite lattice is also a complete lattice but I'dont known where to start.

From definition, a lattice is a poset in which every pair of elements has a least upper bound and a greatest lower bound. If the previous conditions are valid for any subset that the lattice is also complete.

How can I prove that every finite lattice is also complete? I need some hint.

Comment: What would be the least upper bound of three elements x, y, and z? What about the least upper bound of n many elements? Now since your lattice is finite, you'll never have to find a bound on more than finitely many elements. Do you see where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

sup{ $a_1, a_2,.. a_n$ } = $a_1$ sup $a_2$ sup ... sup $a_n$

Comment: This looks like a non-answer; can you please explain a bit more clearly what you are saying?